# MySQL Select first entry of GROUP after custom ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to fetch the first entry of each `group` after the custom `ORDER BY` but don't know how to select that first entry of each group. The groups should be ordered by the `@team` if exist, otherwise other `team` else `NULL`.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tbl t1
INNER JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t2.group_id = t1.group
WHERE t2.region = @region
ORDER BY
CASE
  WHEN team=@team THEN 1
  WHEN team is NOT NULL THEN 2
  WHEN team is NULL THEN 3
END
```

Content of `tbl`

```
id  group   team
1   1       AA
2   1       BB
3   2       AA
4   2       CC
5   3       BB
6   3       NULL
7   4       NULL
```

Expected result when `@team=AA`

```
id  group   team
1   1       AA
3   2       AA
5   3       BB
7   4       NULL
```

Expected result when `@team=BB`

```
id  group   team
2   1       BB
3   2       AA
5   3       BB
7   4       NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your custom ordering logic with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t1.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.`group`
                                    ORDER BY CASE WHEN team = @team THEN 1
                                                  WHEN team IS NOT NULL THEN 2
                                                  ELSE 3 END) rn
    FROM tbl t1
    INNER JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t2.group_id = t1.`group`
    WHERE t2.region = @region
)

SELECT id, `group`, team
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Side note: Avoid naming your table columns `GROUP`, as this is a reserved MySQL keyword, and therefore must always be escaped in backticks.